# Building a Docker container with stack and custom options

Tags: haskell, docker, haskell-stack

There are instructions in the "Docker" section of the [`stack` guide](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#docker) on how to build a Docker container using `stack`. However, I need to supply additional options in the container, namely:

```
RUN mkdir -p /code
VOLUME /code
WORKDIR /code

RUN useradd app --uid 9000
USER app

# Reset fpco/stack-run's dumb ENTRYPOINT
ENTRYPOINT []
CMD ["/usr/bin/engine"]
```

Can these options be configured in the `stack.yaml` file. Note that I don't want to build from a container, but build one from my development environment.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure, but I don't think this can be configured in `stack.yaml`.  I think the solution would be to have your own Dockerfile that generates an image, and then point to this image as the base for your generated docker containers.